# Getting error from heroku in regards to HTTPS

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, heroku, https

I have an app written with angular and deployed over nodejs to heroku.
When I run it in development mode on my home computer everything is awesome, and no errors occur. But once I deliver it to heroku I get the following error message on the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://yasawebsite.herokuapp.com/#/' was loaded
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/asayorku.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=[MY SECTRET API-KEY]&callback=angular.callbacks._0'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Is there an issue with how I call my data from tumblr up?

this is what I am doing:

```
$http.jsonp('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/asayorku.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=[MY SECRET API Key]&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .success(function (data) {
    // my data analysis process
  });
```

And this is what I have setup over at my server.js file

```
var express = require('express')
    , morgan = require('morgan')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , methodOverride = require('method-override')
    , app = express()
    , port = process.env.PORT || 3000
    , router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log('App running on port', port);
```

I'd like to stress that everything works except for the data call I make with $http, should I be using the vanilla js or jquery methods? if so why is this happening o.0 ?

Also the reason it calls a /dist folder is because the app is minified by Grunt first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing your API request to this (make the protocol relative):

```
$http.jsonp('//api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/asayorku.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=[MY SECRET API Key]&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
  .success(function (data) {
    // my data analysis process
  });
```

Comment: @Vapri I just dropped the `http:` part from your API request. It makes the request relative to the current protocol of the page you're on. So on an HTTPS site (such as yours) the request would be to https://api.tumblr…